# Moving data based on information in one column and then sorting by data in another

Tags: vba, excel, automation

Ok so best way to explain this, I have a spreadsheet that is produced monthly. It needs to be automated. From the report that gets shipped into excel I need to take all the data from the project number column and move it to another workbook. In this workbook are worksheets for 2012 and 2013. I need all of the projects starting 300, then 400, then 500 etc to move into the new workbook and then the 2012 projects to go into one worksheet and 2013 into another. How would I go about automating such a thing?

Thanks for any help

300873  *Company Name*                      10/09/2012
300874  *Company Name*                          10/09/2012
412774  *Company Name*                          30-01-12
412972  *Company Name*                          23-05-12
412986  *Company Name*                          17-07-12
413001  *Company Name*                          08/06/13
413048  *Company Name*                          14-08-12
413049  *Company Name*                          14-08-12
413062  *Company Name*                          20-08-13
413068  *Company Name*                          23-08-12
413169  *Company Name*                          21-09-13
510003  *Company Name*                      27-12-12
600161  *Company Name*                          28-02-12

So with these I would want all of the projects with 2012 to go into one sheet and all the others to go into a 2013 sheet in a sperate workbook, I would also need the 300--- projects to go into the spreadsheet and fill rows underneath the number 300 so this might include adding rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can design a macro for this pretty easily. I'm going to give you some tools to use, give it a try, when and if there is something you're running into come back, post your code, and ask more questions on this question you've already made and I'll help you along with the code so you can learn.

> I need to take all the data from the project number column and move it to another workbook.

---

**First, code for Opening a file from your macro:**

```
ChDir "[pathway to the folder]"       'loads file

Workbooks.Open Filename:= "[pathwayToFolder including filename]"

Workbooks("[workbook name]").Activate
```

Something else that is useful is the ability to specifically refer to different sheets and ranges without actually have to select or go to those sheets. This code, for example, writes something specific in a specific workbook, sheet, and range without going to them

```
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5") = "Test"
```

---

**Second, Copying and Pasting:**

This code copies all cells and pastes them all on another sheet, you can obviously copy and paste more specific ranges (google it if you need)

```
Cells.Copy
Sheets("[sheetname]").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

---

**Third, Determining the Year:**

If the date is in Column "C" I would just do this

```
Dim i As Integer, rowNumber As Integer
i = 1         'whatever row your data begins on
rowNumber = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count      'gets used number of rows

Do              'Loops through all data on the sheet

   If Right(Range("C" & i), 2) = "12" Then    'checks the last 2 characters in date column

      'copy data from that row and paste it wherever applicable   

   ElseIf Right(Range("C" & i), 2) = "13" Then  'checks for 2013

      'move 2013 data wherever applicable

   End If

   i = i + 1
Loop Until i = rowNumber
```

---

Try to start putting this code together into something and get back to us on this question.

Also, in the future try to do some of the research and work on this before asking, the question is actually multiple questions and very broad, making it hard to answer. That is why someone downvoted it.

Hope this helps!