# Move rows to another sheet based on criteria in the first column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large spreadsheet (2000+ rows). In the first column are what I call "tag ids", where you have a letter code followed by a space and a combination of letters and numbers, for example `EHV 1087` or `ZHS 99X75B`. The rest of the columns contain irrelevant data.

I want to move rows from this main sheet to separate sheets if the tag ID in the first column starts with one of several letter codes. For example, I want to move all rows where the tag ID starts with "EV", "EC", "DHP" or "LAI" to sheet two.

Is there an easy VBA script to do this or am I out of luck? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving data based on information in one column and then sorting by data in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853800/moving-data-based-on-information-in-one-column-and-then-sorting-by-data-in-anoth)

Comment: Please look down the right side of this page for the **Related** section. There are a half-dozen previous questions listed there that answer your question.

Comment: I've looked through those questions, most of them are talking about a date or a searching criteria that is always a specific number of characters long, and use the Right() function or something like that to match. However, the tag IDs I'm talking about can have any number of characters (in practicality usually between 2 and 6), and I was thinking I might need to use regex or wildcards for it and I haven't seen a response relating to that..

Comment: see [Autofilter for Partial Array strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484479/vba-autofilter-for-partial-array-strings/31484831#31484831).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic algorithm to get you going.

```
'Go to last row in sheet, column A
Selection.End(xlDown).Select

'Find first two letters with the previously mentioned Right() or similar
=LEFT(The cell you are looking in,2)

'See if they match your criteria
IF [the value from above] = ("EV")

'If they do match, move the row to sheet 2
'If they do not match, check the next criteria
 'Do this for all of your four criteria.
 'Go up one row in the document.
 'Repeat process until you are at the top of the document
```